# using python and pandas to combine csv columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two csv data files. PV.csv which has rows like this:

```
date,PVkW
2018/03/05 11:00,887.4
2018/03/05 12:00,940.9
2018/03/05 13:00,927.2
2018/03/05 14:00,845.9
2018/03/05 15:00,683.0
2018/03/05 16:00,423.1
2018/03/05 17:00,186.4
```

and TBL.csv which has rows like this:

```
date,TBLkW
2018/03/05 11:00,277.01953
2018/03/05 12:00,285.30783
2018/03/05 13:00,236.8461
2018/03/05 14:00,243.26564
2018/03/05 15:00,274.98438
2018/03/05 16:00,255.20079
2018/03/05 17:00,262.28046
```

I am using the script below to get a file that contains the entries date,PVkW,TBLkW, but all I am getting is a copy of date,PVkW. What am I missing?

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('PV.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('TBL.csv')
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on='date')
merged.to_csv("combined.csv", index=False)
```

The script is completing without error.

Would this script continue to work if one file had a date entry that the other did not?

Comment: By default, `b.dropna(axis=1)` drops columns with any missing values. Are you sure `b['TBLkW']` doesn't have any missing values? Also could you print `merged`?

Comment: why didn't you try that yourself ? answer is easy to get. If you delete one line, you only get the ones that match. So it keeps working, results differ

Comment: Try `b = b.dropna(axis=0)`  if you want to remove rows with missing values. `axis=1` drops entire columns

Comment: Okay, this is the answer. What would happen if I did not use this line of code at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default mode for pandas.merge is 'inner' which will take the intersection of the two lists. So your script work and it will continue if one file had a date entry that the other does not but if you want your result file to have all data then you should use 'outer' mode.

More info here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

For example with PV.csv like :

```
date,PVkW
2018/03/05 11:00,887.4
2018/03/05 12:00,940.9
2018/03/05 13:00,927.2
2018/03/05 14:00,845.9
2018/03/05 15:00,683.0
2018/03/05 16:00,423.1
2018/03/05 17:00,186.4
2018/03/05 18:00,186.4
```

TBL.csv like :

```
date,TBLkW
2018/03/05 11:00,277.01953
2018/03/05 12:00,285.30783
2018/03/05 13:00,236.8461
2018/03/05 14:00,243.26564
2018/03/05 15:00,274.98438
2018/03/05 16:00,255.20079
2018/03/05 17:00,262.28046
```

And this script :

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('PV.csv')
b = pd.read_csv('TBL.csv')
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, how='outer', on='date')
merged.to_csv("combined.csv", index=False)
```

You get :

```
date,PVkW,TBLkW
2018/03/05 11:00,887.4,277.01953
2018/03/05 12:00,940.9,285.30782999999997
2018/03/05 13:00,927.2,236.8461
2018/03/05 14:00,845.9,243.26564
2018/03/05 15:00,683.0,274.98438
2018/03/05 16:00,423.1,255.20078999999998
2018/03/05 17:00,186.4,262.28046
2018/03/05 18:00,186.4,
```